# SSIS- how to split 1 record into multiples record

Tags: sql, ssis

I have table below:

```
SerialNumber  Name Product

1             aaa  a

2             bbb  b

3             ccc  c
```

I would like to convert to table below:

```
serialNumber PropertyName value

1            Name          aaa

1            Product       a

2            Name          bbb

2            Product       b

3            Name          ccc

3            Product       c
```

How can i achieve this in SSIS 2012?

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141723.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `Pivot` and `Unpivot` Data Flow Transformations, but even simpler it will be for you to use `Multicast`, to make two streams out of one. Then in one stream you'll be passing Names and values, an in the other Products and values. Then use `Union All` to join the streams again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For my source table, number of column is dynamic. In this example, i have product and name. In my real application, it can be more. How can i get the column name for the dynamic column and convert to second table?

Comment: @user3082385 If you have dynamic number of columns, then there's no better way than use a script component as data source, and handle all of this by yourself. Here you'll find some ideas: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/toddmcdermid/2011/05/03/iterating-over-columns-in-the-ssis-script-component/

Comment: Thanks :) then i think i have no choice :(